# Custom field for CMS page in Magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes, content-management-system

I added new field to CMS-> Page Content -> Edit page -> Design tab

```
$designFieldset->addField('header_image', 'image', array(
        'name'      => 'header_image',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Image'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Image'),
        'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
    ));
```

then I added this field to `cms_page` table in database, also added code to `saveAction()` function,
image uploading and saving works normally.

But when I open page for edit, function `getData()` doesn't want to load this field value.
Anyone faced this? 
Thanks.

Comment: My coworker gave me answer for this question. Just need to add the same field to this (enterprise_cms_page_revision) table in database too.

Comment: you may want to post your solution as a separate answer (instead of comment) and then accept it.

Comment: Need to wait few hours, my rating doesn't allow to do it just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My coworker gave me answer for this question. Just need to add the same field to this (enterprise_cms_page_revision) table in database too.

Answer (score 1):

How have you added this code? I had a very similar issue, but that's because I was using the 'adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form' event.

Turns out, this event gets dispatched -after- form values are set from model data:

```
$form->setValues($model->getData());
$this->setForm($form);

Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form', array('form' => $form));
```

Solution for me ended being:

```
class SomeCompany_SomeModule_Block_Cms_Page_Edit_Tab_Content_Observer {

    public function someMethod($observer) {
        $form = $observer->getEvent()->getForm();
        $fieldset = $form->getElement('content_fieldset');
        $fieldset->addField('some_field', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'some_field',
            'label' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Some Field'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Some Field')
        ));

        /*
         * Magento amazingly does this BEFORE firing the event, so it will not
         * populate fields added inside the observer, so call it again to populate
         * our custom fields.
         */
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('cms_page')->getData());
    }

}
```